# Getting a customized row along with the resultant list in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table ctry in Oracle Database schema.This table has columns country_name,city_name,city_id,site_name,site_id...
My requirement is to get the distinct city Id and city name for a particular country.
So my query,
SELECT distinct(city_Id), city_name from ctry where country_name = "somevalue".
gives me the required results.

To this resultant list I would want to add a row having values as
city_id = "(offsite)" and city_name= "OFF site"(which is not there in the table.)

I have used query like 
SELECT distinct(city_Id), city_name from ctry where country_name = "somevalue".
union
select  '(offsite)' AS city_Id, 'OFF SITE' AS city_name from ctry

But here the problem is the resultant list will have multiple values of city_id and city_name as '(offsite)' and 'OFF SITE' respectively.

But I would only want one row with Offsite Values.Is there any way i can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your are not reading data from ctry, you can just use dual table

```
SELECT distinct(city_Id), city_name from ctry where country_name = "somevalue". 
union select '(offsite)' AS city_Id, 'OFF SITE' AS city_name from dual
```